# ssh connection does not work from script

Tags: ssh, wpa-supplicant

The following lines work perfectly if they are executed line by line:

```
sudo -i wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf;
echo "This echo still works.";
sudo -i sshpass -p mypassphrase ssh myusername@192.168.0.2 -T 'sudo mkdir /home/myusername/myFolder';
```

However, executing them as a block or within a script leads to the output

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
This echo still works.
```

and the final line running forever. Also no directory is created.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

**EDIT #1**

Thank you for your answers so far.

@Sotto Voce: Yes, wpa_supplicant brings up the connection that is required for ssh.

@sudodus: Thank you for your answer. It does not require sudo in the ssh command line to reproduce this issue. Sorry, if this was confusing in my original post. Anyway, the simplified code

```
sudo -i wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf;
echo "This echo still works.";
sshpass -p mypassphrase ssh myusername@192.168.0.2 'who';
```

shows the same effect: It works well if pasted and executed from the terminal line by line. However, the final line takes forever if all lines are executed simultaneously (e.g. in one script).

The direction I am currently thinking: Something needs to differ when
`sshpass -p mypassphrase ssh myusername@192.168.0.2 'who';`
is executed solely from terminal or in combination with
`sudo -i wpa_supplicant ...`
Possibly `myusername` is not accepted if `sudo -i` was used upfront?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `-T` option from the ssh command?

Comment: @Sotto Voce: no change in behavior or output.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the `wpa_supplicant` command brings up a network connection that the ssh command depends on to connect to 192.168.0.2?

Comment: @userK, Please tell us what computer (brand name and model), and what operating system (Linux distro and version) that you are running in the client and server. It can help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

My take on the difference between a person typing the commands interactively and the script executing them is:  speed

The `wpa_supplicant` command brings up the network link that ssh needs.  What happens if that network link isn't up when you invoke the ssh command?  On my home computer, my ssh command hangs for a long time because nothing is receiving the SYN packets that start a connection.  Then ssh times out and reports an error.  The same symptoms as you get with your script (though you didn't say whether you waited for the ssh error).

When you type the `wpa_supplicant` command and `ssh` command by hand, there's probably 5-7 seconds in between, which is enough for the network link to come up before the ssh command launches.  When the script executes the commands, there's almost no time in between, and the link isn't ready yet when ssh sends its first SYN packets.

My suggestion is to see if a `sleep 10` line between the `echo` and `sudo ... ssh ...` lines will work for you.

Comment: +1; Good idea to add `sleep`:-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Original answer

I think your problem is not `sshpass` and `ssh` on the client side, but `sudo` on the server side.

One way to bring a password there is to set the variable `SUDO_ASKPASS`. In my main computer, in the file `~/.profile` I have the line

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

and I can check by

```
echo $SUDO_ASKPASS
```

that it is there and by

```
which ssh-askpass
```

that the program is also where it should be. That particular program has a GUI, so I let `ssh -X` make it available to the guest side. You might be able to use the `sshpass -p` on the server side too (you must have access to such operations there).

Anyway this worked for me:

```
ssh -tX myuser@192.168.0.2 'source /home/myuser/.profile; sudo -A fdisk -lu /dev/sda'
```

I typed the `sudo` password of the server in a small window that popped up on the client computer's desktop, and `sudo` ran `fdisk` and showed the result in the active terminal window.

Your situation might be different. First you must check/install a suitable password program, maybe `sshpass` (if you don't want `ssh-askpass`), in the server. Then add the option `-A` to `sudo` on the server side.

I think you can begin the command line with

```
sshpass -p password ssh ...
```

I would not use `sudo` to run `ssh` for security reasons. It is bad enough with the explicit password, but sometimes it will be too cumbersome to keep a high security level.

#### Edit 1:

After the first feedback I tested again, and a script modified from yours only to match my user IDs worked but did not work well, but after adding the option `-t` (lowercase t), it worked better, was also showing how the ssh session was managed. I commented away the line with `wpa_supplicant` because it is not relevant for me (I don't know what it is doing but I hope it does not destroy things for `ssh`).

My script `ssher`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#sudo -i wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf;
echo "This echo still works.";
sshpass -p mypassword  ssh -t sudodus@192.168.0.2 'who';
```

Run without `-t`:

```
$ ./ssher
This echo still works.
olle     tty7         2022-07-18 15:12 (:0)
```

Run with `-t`, as the script is shown above:

```
$ ./ssher
This echo still works.
olle     tty7         2022-07-18 15:12 (:0)
sudodus  pts/1        2022-07-19 22:50 (192.168.0.12)
Connection to 192.168.0.2 closed.
```